# Ставить ли индексы в EF, при связях один ко многим?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, index

У меня есть класс `Message` - сообщение форума, и его можно линковать к себе же посредством связи один ко многим, то есть сообщение может содержать набор других дочерних сообщений (ответы на сообщение), каждый ответ тоже может содержать дочернии любой вложенности.

```
public class Message {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    ...
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Message Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> ChildMessages { get;set; }
}
```

Вопрос такой нужно ли ставить `[Index]` аттрибут у свойства `ParentId`, если при выводе сообщений форума я использую рекурсию по `ChildMessages`? То есть операция `ChildMessages` очень частая.

Вопрос взялся вот откуда.
Конечно я понимаю что для быстрого поиска по полю нужен индекс, но с другой стороны если я объявляю связь много ко многим в EF, и у меня есть поле `ChildMessages` то понятно что я его завёл не просто так, а для того что бы по нему искать. Тогда `EF` мог бы сам проставить все необходимые индексы и сделать необходимые оптимизации.

Comment: Индексы нельзя ставить наугад. Т.е. в это случае вы скорее всего угадаете с индексом, но вообще стоит смотреть профайлером реальные запросы, проверять планы их выполнения - и только потом ставить индексы под них.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, на атрибутах, которые участвуют в связях между сущностями всегда должен стоять индекс(Если конечно таблицы не мизерные, тогда СУБД скорее всего их будет игнорировать).

К тому же, всегда можно протестировать работу с индексом и без него, сравнить планы запросов и на основании это сделать вывод, есть ли от него какой-либо профит или нет.

Даже многие среды проектирования БД автоматически ставят на такие атрибуты индексы.

А вот ставить ли индекс на другие атрибуты- это уже выясняется анализом планов выполнения запросов и т п.